# Android: TabManager class can't be resolved, inheriting from FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-tabhost

I am following the example here

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html

creating tabs using fragments and in the tutorial it uses TabManager but on my version it says  it cannot be resolved.

I am using minsdk set to 14 and targetsdk set to 15.

I don't wish to use the backward compatible support.

Any ideas which package it is in?

Eclipse doesn't provide me any help, only asks me to create the class TabManager.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TabManager` is for the compatibility fragment tabs, not for the 3.0+ fragment tabs. That's why it can't be resolved.

The tutorial here shows how to create fragment tabs in 3.0+:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#newTab()

Also, you don't have to inherit from `FragmentActivity` starting in Honeycomb unless you want backwards compatibility.  You can just inherit from `Activity` and `Fragment` will be supported.

Comment: Thanks!, thats great, but the example uses the ActionBar, i thought it was the standard to use the fragments?? not the actionbar?

Comment: With the actionbar tabs no layout file is needed which includes the tabcontent, tabwidget etc?

Comment: The ActionBar will take care of laying out and displaying the tabs.  Starting in Honeycomb, it's standard behavior to use the ActionBar for navigation.  You still use Fragment classes for your content, just keep the navigation in the ActionBar.  You can even see that by selecting a tab from the ActionBar, you get a FragmentTransaction in the the TabListener to do your Fragment work.

Comment: ah i think i got it now, in v3 and below you can't use the actionbar so you can't use the tabs in actionbars so for backward compatible you have to use fragments.... i seemed to have missed that somewhere..  thanks for the explanation

Comment: Glad you understand it. Let me know if there's anything else you need clarified. Don't forget to accept the answer if it solves your question so that others may benefit from it.